# How do you populate a ExpandableListView with two different Objects

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a Expandable List View and want to populate it with two different objects, currently I am just filling the children with a Tareas Object, but want to fill the same children list with a different Object (Metas). How can I achieve this, since my adapter is just populating the list with Tareas Objects and is not taking in the Metas Object.

> ***UPDATE***

This is my ExpandableListViewAdapter:

```
public class CalendarioAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private List<String> mCalendarioListHeader;
private HashMap<String, List<Object>> mCalendarioListChild;
private static final int CHILD_TYPE_META = 0;
private static final int CHILD_TYPE_PLANES = 1;


public CalendarioAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                         HashMap<String, List<Object>> listChildData) {
    this.mContext= context;
    this.mCalendarioListHeader= listDataHeader;
    this.mCalendarioListChild = listChildData;
}
@Override
public int getChildTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}


@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.mCalendarioListHeader.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    List childList = mCalendarioListChild.get(mCalendarioListHeader.get(groupPosition));
    if (childList != null && ! childList.isEmpty()) {
        return childList.size();
    }
    return 0;
}


@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this.mCalendarioListHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return this.mCalendarioListChild.get(this.mCalendarioListHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    String listSize = getChildrenCount(groupPosition) +"";
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.calendario_list_header, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    TextView sizeOfList = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.calendarioListSize);
    sizeOfList.setText(listSize);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    Integer childType = (getChildType(groupPosition, childPosition));
    Log.d("childType", childType+"");

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null|| convertView.getTag() != childType) {

        switch (childType) {

            case CHILD_TYPE_META:
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.metas_list_row, null);
                convertView.setTag(childType);
                break;
            case CHILD_TYPE_PLANES:
                convertView =  layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.calendario_list_row, null);
                convertView.setTag(childType);
                break;
            default:

                break;
        }
    }
    switch (childType) {
        case CHILD_TYPE_META:
            Metas metas = (Metas) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
            TextView txtMetasChild =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.metasTxtChild);
            TextView fechaMetasChild = convertView.findViewById(R.id.fechaMetaChild);
            txtMetasChild.setText(metas.getMeta());
            fechaMetasChild.setText(metas.getFecha());
            break;
        case CHILD_TYPE_PLANES:
            Tareas tareas = (Tareas) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
            TextView txtDescripcionChild = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.descripcionTareaText);
            TextView txtListaChild = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.listaTareaText);
            txtDescripcionChild.setText(tareas.getDescripcion());
            txtListaChild.setText(tareas.getLista());
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return convertView;


  }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        Object child = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        Log.d("ChildType", child+"");
        if(child instanceof Metas){
            return CHILD_TYPE_META;
        } else if(child instanceof Tareas) {
            return CHILD_TYPE_PLANES;
        }
        else{
// should never happen, so do error handling here
            throw new RuntimeException("only classes Metas and Tareas permitted");
        }
    }
}
```

> And on my Fragment I populate the list like this:

```
       private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<Object>>();

        // Adding header data
        listDataHeader.add(diasText[0]);
        listDataHeader.add(diasText[1]);
        listDataHeader.add(diasText[2]);
        listDataHeader.add(diasText[3]);
        listDataHeader.add(diasText[4]);
        listDataHeader.add(diasText[5]);
        listDataHeader.add(diasText[6]);

        // Adding child data

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), dia1List);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), dia2List);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), dia3List);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), dia4List);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), dia5List);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(5), dia6List);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(6), dia7List);
    }
```

Any idea of how can I achieve my request will be highly appreciated!

Comment: You mean that you want to use this same adapter with multiple inputs?  You could create a base class that each of these extends and use that as your List object such as List<BaseClass> and do a type check if necessary on the BaseClass to take appropriate action if that is what you are after (instanceof Tareas).  Not sure if I follow correctly though.  You might be better off creating multiple adapters depending on the difficulty involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When subclassing `BaseExpandableListAdapter`, you can provide different `View` types for the group items as well as for the child items. I'll only sketch how to do different child `View` types because that's what you want to do (and the post will get long enough even so) .

`View` types are represented by `int` values, e.g.

```
private static final int TYPE_TAREAS = 0;
private static final int TYPE_METAS = 2;
```

So in your case you pass in a `HashMap<String, List<Object>>` instead of a `HashMap<String, List<Tareas>>` and override `getChildTypeCount()` to return 2 (the number of different Viewtypes). (Of course you can also use any common ancestor of `Tareas` and `Metas` instead of `Object`)

Then you override `getChildType (int groupPosition, int childPosition)` to return the correct `int` value (TYPE_TAREAS or TYPE_METAS) for the `View` type for this specific entry. To determine the type, use `instanceof` on the `List` entry.

Finally, when overriding `getChildView()`, you do the necessary type cast on the `List` entry and determine the `View` type by calling `getChildType()`. As always with `ListView`, you may be able to reuse *convertView*.

Here's what the [documentation for getChildView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter#getChildView(int,%20int,%20boolean,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) says on this topic:

> convertView   View: the old view to reuse, if possible. You should check that this view is non-null and of an appropriate type before using. If it is not possible to convert this view to display the correct data, this method can create a new view. It is not guaranteed that the convertView will have been previously created by getChildView(int, int, boolean, View, ViewGroup).

If *convertView* can't be reused you create a new `View` according to the `View` type by inflating the required layout.
It is a good idea to follow the ViewHolder pattern. You may need two completely different ViewHolders or one extending from the other, that depends on the differences between your two data classes.

The rest is business as usual :-)

Comment: It doesnt accept Object as a parameter ;/ I did everything else, any suggestion to fix that?

Comment: @AlfonsoBriceño - what is "It"?

Comment: If you're talking about the Constructor of the Adapter - sorry I did not mention it but you have to switch from HashMap<String, List<Tareas>> to HashMap<String, List<Object>>  in the Constructor as well.

Comment: When setting the child data I use a list of Tareas and Metas, but it throws me a error of wrong type of argument found Metas/Tareas insted of Object.

Comment: You can post your code [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173580/discussion-between-0x0nosugar-and-alfonso-briceno) and I'll look into it. Unfortunately it is getting a bit late around here but I'll get back to you tomorrow. OK?

Comment: I did change it, the problem is when I am adding the child data it thows me the error of: Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.util.List<com.albot.focus.Elementos.Tareas>', required: 'java.util.List<java.lang.Object>

Comment: OK, I see. I remember now there is a problem with casting Lists in Java. Sorry, my bad. So you need to fill the Tareas / Metas elements into a new List<Object> before passing them to the Adapter. If this does not work my offer with dumping the code to the chat remains valid.